# Unable to import numpy/pandas/matplotlib packages in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, package

I have used widely used packages(installed via pip) for a while in Jupyter notebook without any issues. I tried to do Python coding in VScode,but it somehow cannot load those packages.

I have tried changing python interpreter, but it did solve the issue. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: _I have tried changing python interpreter, but it did not work_ What do you mean "it did not work"?  Do you mean you were able to change the interpreter, but it did not solve the import issue?  Or you weren't able to change the interpreter?

Comment: I was able to change the interpreter, but did not solve the import issue.

Comment: What did you change the interpreter to?

Comment: You use the `.py` file or the jupyter notebook provided in vscode? At the same time, have you selected the interpreter which python packages installed in?

Comment: Can you share more details, like a specific error message?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have the python interpreter installed on your computer. In your vscode UI you should see a terminal. You can install and upgrade pip through there if needed by using these commands:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

From here you should be able to import using pip commands.